# How to override cell style for xib-less cell inherited from MvxBindableTableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm trying to inherit from MvxBindableTableViewCell to redefine my own cell (with more text fields and images).
When a new instance is created from MyCustomSource.GetOrCreateCell, the ctor used is always MyCustomCell(IntPtr handle). In this case, the cell style used is Default, but I want to use the Value1 style (to reuse the right-aligned blue text).

In a traditional iOS app, the solution will be to use from my ctor the "initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:" base ctor.
For a MonoTouch/MvvmCross project, the right solutino will be probably to do it in the XCode designer. But I'm working from VS (cannot use my solution with XS) and I want to use only xib-less UI to be able to track changes on them in my source control.

Any idea on how to achieve my aim?

Guillaume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I don't tend to use the standard cell types very much. Instead I tend to build my own custom cells using either XIB or manual-code-based layout.

However, you can easily use the standard cell types if you want to in Mvx.

In v3, you can choose to use the `MvxStandardTableViewCell` constructor which takes a `UITableViewCellStyle` as a parameter - e.g. see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxStandardTableViewCell.cs#L40

This is also exposed up to the constructors for the `MvxStandardTableViewSource` https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxStandardTableViewSource.cs#L60

---

In vNext last year, I think the same functionality was exposed via the old `MvxSimpleBindableTableViewSource` - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxSimpleBindableTableViewSource.cs#L62

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stuart. I will use my own cell type as you without relying to any cell style consideration, seems to be a better idea in fact.

But I'm facing a new trouble: when trying to add my UI elements to the ContentView from the ctor (as explained by Xam in their tutorial), this one seems to has not been initialized yet (which is not the case while using a UICollectionViewCell). Is this why you use a third method "Initialize" on your custom cell? Or is it a glitch on my side?